# how to change decimal to numeric on y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to convert decimal to numeric on y axis automatically?

not manually because some plot have larger amount of data on that time if we do manually it takes more time

```
ggplot(data = dd_pard_Last_3M, aes(x = m_year, y = PARD)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill=status))+theme_classic()+
      #geom_line(data = plan_DD_pard(), aes(x=m_year, y= PARD, group=1,color="Plan"),size=1.2)+
      scale_colour_manual(name="",values=Plan)+
      #geom_point(data = plan_DD_pard(), aes(x=m_year, y=PARD),color="#288D55")+
      theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank(),legend.position = "bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 10, angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
      labs(x="", y="Agreements Values (In Lakhs)", fill="")+
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#284a8d", "#00B5CE","#0590eb","#2746c2"))+
      scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))
```

sample output

[image]

Comment: Could you post a data example?

Comment: And what do you mean by "decimal to numeric"?  Decimal (floating point?) *is* a form of numeric...

Comment: kindly look at the sample image @Limey

Comment: I have.  Your y-axis label values are 0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00.  These can be described as decimal numerics.  Hence my question.  And it would be easier to help you if you posted the image as part of your question rather than as a link and gave us some indication of your *expected output*.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: just want to change the values from 0 to 1 @Limey

Answer (score 0):

Edit : Using solution from https://joshuacook.netlify.app/post/integer-values-ggplot-axis/

I think you are asking to force the y axis labling to display only integer numbers. I've pasted a "helper" formula, and added `breaks = integer_breaks()` to your `scale_y_continuous()` code.

```
# A function factory for getting integer y-axis values.
integer_breaks <- function(n = 5, ...) {
  fxn <- function(x) {
    breaks <- floor(pretty(x, n, ...))
    names(breaks) <- attr(breaks, "labels")
    breaks
  }
  return(fxn)
}

ggplot(data = dd_pard_Last_3M, aes(x = m_year, y = PARD)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill=status))+theme_classic()+
      #geom_line(data = plan_DD_pard(), aes(x=m_year, y= PARD, group=1,color="Plan"),size=1.2)+
      scale_colour_manual(name="",values=Plan)+
      #geom_point(data = plan_DD_pard(), aes(x=m_year, y=PARD),color="#288D55")+
      theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank(),legend.position = "bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 10, angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
      labs(x="", y="Agreements Values (In Lakhs)", fill="")+
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#284a8d", "#00B5CE","#0590eb","#2746c2"))+
      scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE), breaks = integer_breaks())
```

Comment: Updated answer using https://joshuacook.netlify.app/post/integer-values-ggplot-axis/

Comment: Thanks you so much that is what i want